# Join 2 tables and Count the number of occurrence specific field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, group-by

I have 2 tables , "T_COMMON_COUNTRY" and "T_HEI_STUDENTDATA." using left join I joined these tables

this is my query

```
SELECT 
    [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY_ID], 
    [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY], 
    [T_HEI_STUDENTDATA].[STUDENT_ID]

FROM ([T_COMMON_COUNTRY]

 LEFT JOIN [T_HEI_STUDENTDATA]

 ON [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY] = [T_HEI_STUDENTDATA].[STDCOUNTRY])
```

now I' getting view like this

```
 |   Country ID   |     County      | Student ID |
 |       1        |      USA        |     12     |
 |       1        |      USA        |     5      |
 |       2        |      UK         |     11     |
 |       2        |      UK         |     2      |
```

I want Count the number of students (Student_IDs) relate to a country ,

I want get a view exactly like below

```
 |   Country ID   |     County      | Students |
 |       1        |      USA        |     2    |
 |       2        |      UK         |     2    |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `COUNT` function to generate countrywise student count

Try this:

```
SELECT C.[COUNTRY_ID], C.[COUNTRY], COUNT(S.[STUDENT_ID]) AS StudentCount
FROM [T_COMMON_COUNTRY] C
LEFT JOIN [T_HEI_STUDENTDATA] S ON C.[COUNTRY] = S.[STDCOUNTRY]
GROUP BY C.[COUNTRY_ID], C.[COUNTRY];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` function to count the number of students `GROUP BY` Country_ID  and Country.

```
 SELECT 
        [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY_ID], 
        [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY], 
        COUNT([T_HEI_STUDENTDATA].[STUDENT_ID]) AS Students

    FROM ([T_COMMON_COUNTRY]

     LEFT JOIN [T_HEI_STUDENTDATA]

     ON [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY] = [T_HEI_STUDENTDATA].[STDCOUNTRY])
    GROUP BY [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY_ID], [T_COMMON_COUNTRY].[COUNTRY]
```